# DataSpell: Jupyter server failed to start

Tags: jupyter-notebook, dataspell

I am getting following error while trying to run a jupyter-notebook cell from DataSpell. Can anyone suggest about how to get rid of this?

Thanks in advance.

[image: DataSpell]

Answer (score 2):

You just have to set a Python Interpreter for the project.

Preferences -> Python Interpreter (under Project Workspace) -> Select or Add an interpreter

Note: Then after that select Managed: from the top left menu to choose Jupyter server automatically and start it automatically. Other wise you need to start Jupyter manually and feed the tokens at run time.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and finally realized that the problem was the Interpreter misconfiguration.

1. Download [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual).
2. Install Anaconda using the [installation instructions](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/).
3. [Run Anaconda Navigator](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/verify-install/#anaconda-navigator) and in the left hand-side, click on the "Environments" tab.
4. In this section you can see the existing "Environments" or create a new environment, the default mode is **base (root)**.
5. Open DataSpell, go to the Interpreter and select the environment you see in number 4.

> File | Settings | Project | Python Interpreter **for Windows and Linux**

> DataSpell | Preferences | Project | Python Interpreter **for macOS**