# JetBrains DataSpell only restarts the jupyter kernel after clicking the restart button 2 times

Tags: python, jupyter, jetbrains-ide, dataspell

I installed DataSpell on Ubuntu, but when I try to restart the kernel on a Jupyter notebook the code doesn't run again until I restart again.

In the pictures we can see clearly, after the first restart it appears HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found and in the third picture after clicking again on restart the kernel is actually restarted.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: A similar question was asked before. You can add your problems there to avoid the repeated question. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69987353/dataspell-jupyter-server-failed-to-start

Comment: by the way, I reinstalled DataSpell and now I do not find the error.